# Download automatico por bat - Ver data de arquivo antes de baixar

Tags: cmd, download, prompt

Estou querendo criar um script no prompt do windows para atualizar o sistema automaticamente. Mas só quero baixar se tiver atualização nova. Alguém poderia me dizer como poderia verificar a data do arquivo (.rar) antes de baixar ?
Caso contrário, efetuo o download e depois verifico a data...

Obrigado.

Comment: Onde está o arquivo RAR?

Comment: Em um link direto de download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

- Apenas ver a data do arquivo obtendo ultima modificação:`

  ---

```bat
cUrl.exe -# -I https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar |find "Last-Modified"
```

---

- **output**:

  ---

```bat
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Dec 2009 09:50:15 GMT
```

---

> - As duas tarefas de verificar e baixar em um comando:  **<kbd>Wget -N</kbd>**  *ou*  **<kbd>cUrl -Z --time-cond</kbd>**

---

Se considerar fazer uso de alguma ferramenta externa para fazer, a verificação e o download de sua atualização não usando um **`VBS.script`** **`Powershell`** ou **`C#`**, para a verificação de datas entre os arquivos local/remoto, sugiro tentar com o **`Wget.exe`** e/ou o **`cUrl.exe`**.

---

> - Tanto o **cUlr.exe** e o **Wget.exe**, trazem o suporte para verificação das datas entre os **arquivos_locais** e os **arquivos_remotos**, onde é possível  fazer o download do arquivo mais recente **(atualização)**...

---

> - Com uso do **`Wget.exe`**, poderias tentar o seguinte comando:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_arq_rar=G:\SO_pt-BR\Q407637\WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar"
set "_link_rar=https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar

Wget.exe -N "!_arq_rar!" "!_link_rar!"
```

---

O **Wget.exe -N** vai instruir o **`Wget.exe`** para somente fazer o download do arquivo quando o remoto é mais recente que o arquivo local apontado no comando.

> - O arquivo local deve pré-existir para fazer essa comparação...

---

> - Com uso do **`cUrl.exe`**, poderias tentar o seguinte comando:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_arq_rar=G:\SO_pt-BR\Q407637\WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar"
set "_link_rar=https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar

cUrl -Z --time-cond "!_arq_rar!" "!_link_rar!" --output "!_arq_rar!"
```

---

O **cUrl.exe -Z --time-cond "!_arq_rar!"** vai instruí o **`curl.exe`** para comparar a data do arquivo local apontado no comando, com a data do arquivo remoto presente no link, assim, se o arquivo remoto for mais recente, ai ele vai fazer o download para o usuário.

> - O arquivo local deve pré-existir para fazer essa comparação...

---

> - Links Wget.exe 32/64bits:

Wget.exe 64-Bits:

https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/1.20.3/64/wget.exe

Wget.exe 32-Bits:

https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/1.20.3/32/wget.exe

Documentação: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/

> - Links cUrl.exe 32/64bits:

cUrl.exe 64-Bits:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.66.0_2/curl-7.66.0_2-win64-mingw.zip

cUrl.exe 32-Bits:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.66.0_2/curl-7.66.0_2-win32-mingw.zip

Documentação: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

---

> A sugestões acima consideram que os executáveis foram adicionadas na mesma pasta do arquivo cmd/bat e é a mesma pasta onde vai salvar os arquivos, caso contrario, adicione uma variável que aponte para a pasta do executável, ficando:
>
> - Para uso com **Wget** em outra pasta:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"

rem :: se usar o wget.exe ::
set "_wget=c:\pasta_do_Wget"

set "_arq_rar=G:\SO_pt-BR\Q407637\WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar"
set "_link_rar=https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar

pushd "!_Wget!" & Wget.exe -N "!_link_rar!" & popd
```

---

> - Para uso com **cUrl** em outra pasta:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"

rem :: se usar o cUrl.exe ::
set "_cUrl=c:\pasta_do_curl"

set "_arq_rar=G:\SO_pt-BR\Q407637\WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar"
set "_link_rar=https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar

pushd "!_cUrl!" & cUrl.exe -Z --time-cond "!_arq_rar!" "!_link_rar!" --output "!_arq_rar!" & popd
```

---

Para vosso teste, edite as variáveis pertinentes:

---

```bat
rem :: caso use o Wget.exe ::
set "_Wget=c:\pasta_do_Wget"

:: ou ::
rem :: caso use o cUrl.exe ::
set "_cUrl=c:\pasta_do_cUrl"

set "_arq_rar=G:\SO_pt-BR\Q407637\WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar"
set "_link_rar=https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar
```

---

Para ver a data antes de fazer o download e salvando numa variável:

---

```bat
rem :: Usando cUrl.exe ::
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^>: %i in ('curl -s -v -X HEAD https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar 2^>^&1 ^| find "-modified"')do (set "_dtmod=%i" & cmd /v/c echo/%i)

rem :: Usando Wget.exe ::
for /f ^tokens^=2*delims^=: %i in ('wget --server-response --spider "https://www.rarlab.com/themes/WinRAR_Noia_Bogart_64x64.theme.rar" ^2^>^&1 ^| find /i "modified"')do (set "_dtmod=%i" & cmd/v/c echo/%i)
```

Comment: Para funcionar é necessário que exista um arquivo local, porque vai verificar as datas entre o arquivo remoto e o arquivo local...

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho um link de um arquivo .rar para testar mais vou te dar um exemplo usando um arquivo zip e a ferramenta curl:

```
curl -I https://www.macrorecorder.com/MacroRecorder_Portable.zip 2> Nul | find /i "last-modified"
```

Isso vai resultar em algo como:
last-modified: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 15:18:29 GMT

A ferramenta curl já está incluida nas últimas versões do Windows 10 e se não tiver é só baixar.